# Possible duplicate link missing

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

I originally posted a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016665/byte-to-string-without-knowing-the-coding) which contained a link to a possible duplicate question. I figured the question was more suited to be closed with [this duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025332/determine-a-strings-encoding-in-c-sharp), so I deleted my comment and then clicked Close and pasted in the same link for the duplicate question. The Possible Duplicate comment was never autogenerated by the system.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the system does that so as not to add too many comments. When voting to close the question though both duplicate options appear and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025332/determine-a-strings-encoding-in-c-sharp) has more votes so when the question is eventually closed it's likely it will be closed as a duplicate of that in which case all's well that ends well isn't it?